# Pulling data in JSON format from URL

Tags: php, json

Hi i have been trying to pull data in JSON format. Here is my code

```
$resourse_url  = 'http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=list_vendor_name';
$json_data = file_get_contents($resourse_url);
$json_output = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);

$vendor = $json_output['vendor_name'][1];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($vendor);
exit(1);
```

However when i run the code it does not return anything. When i try to access the source URL via firefox, it asks me where to save the JSON data as *.php, however when i access the source URL from Chrome it displays the JSON data as normal.

What do i have to do here? Can anyone point me to a solution? Thx

Comment: It's invalid JSON: `Parse error on line 33:
...     "vendor_name": "Nanny\'s Pavillion 
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['`. Check out [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) and paste in your JSON to verify it. (It's the escaped `'` in `Nanny\'s Pavillion (Central Park)` which is causing the problem.) Perhaps try to do a `$json_data = str_replace("\'", "'", $json_data);` because parsing it. You also **have** to use `$json_output['result'][0]['vendor_name']` for it to work correctly.

Comment: Thx for the great tool to verify JSON data. Thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running the returned json on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "vendor_id":"726",
         "vendor_name":"Scusa"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"519",
         "vendor_name":"Emilie French Restaurant and Bar"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"482",
         "vendor_name":"Cassis French Fine Dining"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"435",
         "vendor_name":"Asuka Japanase Dining"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"12050",
         "vendor_name":"Taipan"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"12061",
         "vendor_name":"Social House"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"12103",
         "vendor_name":"Harum Manis Indonesian Restaurant"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"12193",
         "vendor_name":"Nanny\'s Pavillion (Central Park)"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"12272",
         "vendor_name":"Bistro Baron"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"20704",
         "vendor_name":"Kitchenette (Central Park)"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"21217",
         "vendor_name":"Kitchenette (Plaza Indonesia)"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"29859",
         "vendor_name":"Momento Restaurant And Bar"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"31055",
         "vendor_name":"Tortuga Kitchen And Bar"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"31056",
         "vendor_name":"Tuck And Chug"
      },
      {
         "vendor_id":"31060",
         "vendor_name":"AUROZ Gourmet Grill"
      }
   ]
}
```

it found invalid characters on this line

```
"vendor_name":"Nanny\'s Pavillion (Central Park)"
```

Comment: the idea of searching json validator did not come across my mind until now. Thx, this helps me a lot to see the reason why my code didn't work. Thx to H2ooooooooo too..